# Implementing a counter in for

Tags: for-loop, clojure

I would like to iterate over a collection and at the same time also maintain a counter ex

```
(for [x (range 10) y (inc 0)] [x y] )
```

I would like 'y' to represent the counter, so for every element the output is ( [0 0] [ 1 1] [2 2]...). How do I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`indexed`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure-contrib/seq-api.html#clojure.contrib.seq/indexed) from `clojure.contrib.seq`. Example:

```
(indexed '(a b c d))  =>  ([0 a] [1 b] [2 c] [3 d])
```

You can also use [`map-indexed`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/map-indexed). Example:

```
(map-indexed vector "foobar")  =>  ([0 \f] [1 \o] [2 \o] [3 \b] [4 \a] [5 \r])
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `map-indexed`, as Simeon advices. In the `for` context it's convenient to use destructuring to get easy access to both the counter and the collection elements:

```
(for [ [y x] (map-indexed vector (range 10) ) ] [x y] )

> ([0 0] [1 1] [2 2] [3 3] [4 4] [5 5] [6 6] [7 7] [8 8] [9 9])
```

Answer (score 2):

I figure if this question still had not been marked as "answered", there may be something else you are looking for, and perhaps it is the flexibility to define your own counter.

I agree with others that for the specific problem you outline, `map-indexed` is the way to go. However, if you insist on using `for`, I would recommend something like this:

```
(for [[x y] (map vector (range 10) (iterate inc 0))]
  [x y])
```

Rafal has a very similar answer, except that the counter will always start from zero and increment by 1. In my version you could define your counter as you see fit. For example, by changing the above `(iterate inc 0)` to `(iterate #(+ 2 %) 10)`, you could instead have a counter that starts at 10 and increments by 2.

Answer (score 1):

```
(keep-indexed (fn [i el][el i]) (range 10))
```

or

```
(keep-indexed #(vec [%2 %1]) (range 10))
(keep-indexed #(identity [%2 %1]) (range 10))
;([0 0] [1 1] [2 2] [3 3] [4 4] [5 5] [6 6] [7 7] [8 8] [9 9])
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, remember that using indexes in Clojure is generally a code smell.